# Triggering dayClick of fullCalendar with agendaDay view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Consider this HTML

```
<tr class="fc-slot120 ">
    <th class="fc-agenda-axis fc-widget-header">4PM</th>
    <td class="fc-widget-content">
        <div style="position: relative;"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When the `td.fc-widet-content` is clicked, the dayClick event is called as expected.  I want to extend this functionality to the `th` that has the time, to allow for easier overbooking.  This code does get called, but does not trigger the dayClick.

```
$('.fc-agenda-axis.fc-widget-header').click(function() {
    $(this).find('td.fc-widget-content').trigger('click');
});
```

Any ideas how to trigger the `dayClick` event that is on the content `td`?  If I directly click the `td.fc-widget-content` element, the dayClick fires as expected.

Comment: This is just a regular jQuery/JS click event. It appears to have nothing to do with the specific "dayClick" callback function provided by fullCalendar. I'm confused by your use of the term "dayClick" in relation to the code above. Can you clarify?

Comment: @ADyson this is an event of the fullCalendar.js control that is triggered by clicking one of the slots.

Comment: ok but it's one that you've defined by setting an event on some CSS classes. It's not the same as the ["dayClick" callback](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayClick) which is specified as part of the calendar options. I'm a bit puzzled as to why you can't just use that callback directly rather than trying to attach events directly to the classes (especially when the HTML and class structure is liable to be different between different view types, and may change without warning between releases of fullCalendar). Is there any particular reason you didn't use the documented feature?

Comment: Perhaps I missed the point of your question, but it's unclear to me what issue prompted you to try and implement a "day" click function in this way.

Comment: the dayClick event of the fullCalendar is triggered when I click on td.fc-widget-content.  I want the same action when I click on the .fc-agenda-axis.fc-widget-header, which is the column that has the time displayed.  How would I trigger that?

Comment: for clarity, which view type(s) are we talking about here? month? agenda? basic? list? timeline? They all have different HTML.

Comment: @ADyson defaultView: 'agendaDay'

Comment: Ok. And you don't need to support any other view types in your calendar? Not even an agenda week or something?

Comment: @ADyson No sir, just that one.

Comment: And which version of fullCalendar? Because as far as I can see there is no "fc-agenda-axis" class used currently, just "fc-axis". See http://jsfiddle.net/ods4h6cj/ (using fullCalendar 3.9, which is almost the latest version)

Comment: Anyway, assuming that class _does_ exist, `$(this).find` will never find the `fc-widget-content` element, because `this` corresponds to the `th` and the `td` is the sibling of that element, not a child within it. `.find()` only locates elements _within_ another element. Using siblings (or just next() in this case might be more efficient) is more suitable as per the answer below.

Comment: @ADyson version 1.5.4

Comment: Ah ok. You are using an out of date, unsupported version. I'd strongly recommend upgrading so you can take advantage of new features and not fall behind. Possibly you might want to wait for the impending version 4 which is currently in beta and is a significant re-write and enhancement. (P.S. This is not an advert, I have no connection to the fullCalendar project, that's just my personal opinion)

Comment: @ADyson That will get added to the todo list.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try use siblings

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   
    $('.fc-widget-header').click(function() {
      $(this).siblings('.fc-widget-content').trigger('click');
  });
     
    $('.fc-widget-content').on('click', function() {
      console.log('click')
      alert('.fc-widget-content clicked')
    })
});
```

```css
.fc-widget-header {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  color:white
}

.fc-widget-content {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="fc-slot120">
    <th class="fc-agenda-axis fc-widget-header">4PM</th>
    <td  class="fc-widget-content">
         testt
        <div style="position: relative;"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This triggered the event as expected, thank you.  Now I have the next step to figure out, why they time doesn't match up to the slot that was triggered.